# RxJava. Zip operator: sequence contains no elements exception

Tags: rx-java

Code throws `Sequence contains no elements` exception. How to fix it?

```
Observable<Entity> observable = observable.fromCallable(…);
Observable<Entity> subObservable1 = observable.flatMap(…)
Observable<Entity> subObservable2 = observable.flatMap(…)
Observable<OtherEntity> subObservable3 = subObservable2.reduce(…); 
Observable<List<AnotherEntity>> subObservable4 = subObservable3.map(…);

return Observable.zip(
    observable, subObservable1, subObservable2, 
    subObservable3, subObservable4) -> … );
```

I suppose problem is related to the Zip operator because of `observable` is used 3 times (in `zip(...)`, in `subObservable1`, in `subObservable2`);

I tried to share first `observable`, also tried to publish it, but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I think some sort of `publish` & `connect` would be the solution here.  Please could you add the code from when you tried `publish`

Comment: It depends on what `observable` does and if `subObservable1` and `subObservable2` become empty after the transformation. Please provide more details on those. In addition, how do you consume the zip?

Comment: @Jahnold, `ConnectableObservable<Entity> observable = observable.fromCallable(…).publish();
Observable<Entity> subObservable1 = observable.flatMap(…)
Observable<Entity> subObservable2 = observable.flatMap(…)
observable.connect();
Observable<OtherEntity> subObservable3 = subObservable2.reduce(…); 
Observable<List<AnotherEntity>> subObservable4 = subObservable3.map(…);

return Observable.zip(
    observable, subObservable1, subObservable2, 
    subObservable3, subObservable4) -> … );` ——— It infinitely hungs execution thread